# Changing classes with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/PXU2w/8/

***CODE***

```
$('#navigation').hover(function() {

    //Check if element with class 'author' exists, if so change it to 'authornew'
    if ($('div.menu-description').length != 0) $('div.menu-description').removeClass('menu-description').addClass('menu-descriptionnew');
    //Check if element with class 'authornew' exists, if so change it to 'author'
    else if ($('div.menu-descriptionnew').length != 0) $('div.menu-descriptionnew').removeClass('menu-descriptionnew').addClass('menu-description');
 });
});
```

What I want is when hovered on the background text color of the `menu-description` class should change to `menu-descriptionnew`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the JS Lint button, to the top of your linked demo, reports several errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right, but you have a syntax error in the Javascript part.
The last closing brackets were not necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/PXU2w/9/

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute of an HTML element should not contain spaces. The selector #navigation li a is looking for an anchor inside a list item that is a descendent of an element with id = navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. Your html:

```
<div id="navigation li a">
    Hover over me
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#navigation li a {

}
```

Id attributes cannot contain spaces, and it looks like your trying to apply a complete CSS selector as the Id of the div element. If you look at your CSS, the selector is for an achor (a), within a list item (li), within the element with id `#navigation`. Change two things:

```
<div id="navigation">Hover over me</div>
```

And:

```
#navigation { }
```

That will correctly apply the background to your `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

"navigation li a" is a selector for this html

```
<ul id="navigation">
   <li><a>you select this element</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xe9B3/